# как добится того чтобы деструктор __del__ отрабатывал при стутасе теста fail

Tags: python, test-automation, pytest

в моих тестах мне понадобился деструктор который проводит определенные манипуляции с тестовыми данными по окончании теста. Проблема заключается в том, что он падает в случае если тест падает

```
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

т.е. интерпритатор заканчивает свою работу до вызова **del**
можно ли как-то решить данную проблему?

Comment: Тестовые данные создаете с помощью fixture?

Comment: немного не правильно выразился, __del__ выполняет метод который условно обновляет значение где-то в бд

Comment: Во-первых, `__del__` это не деструктор. Во-вторых, нет никаких гарантий, что он вообще будет вызван, поэтому возлагать на него какие-то важные задачи не стоит. Для задач тестирования существуют teardown, pytest-фикстуры (см. ответ) и прочие аналоги

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема с `__del__` такая, что в принципе не гарантируется его вызов. Там нельзя ничего критичного делать, для инициализации/очистки нужно использовать другие подходы, и в pytest, в частности, есть свои основанные на fixtures.

Для инициализации объекта, который нужен тесту создайте `fixture`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_test_object():
    try:
       obj = ...  # создаем объект как-то
       yield obj  # здесь будет вызван тест
    finally:
       # тут делаем очистку
```

И используем теперь в тесте:

```
def test_something(my_test_object):
   # используем тут my_test_object
```